# check for internet connectivity using WebSocketLink from apollo-link-ws

Tags: websocket, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm trying to check for internet connectivity using apollo websockets, the purpose of this is to show a "you're disconnected" message when there is no connection to prevent the user from typing and assuming the changes are saved (the changes are supposedly saved on type), here's part of the setup of apollo-link-ws

```
const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
uri: `ws://${hostname}${port ? `:${port}` : ''}/subscriptions`,
options: {
 reconnect: true,
 connectionParams: () => ({
  authorization: localStorage.getItem('accelerator-token')
 })
}
});
```

and

```
    const hasSubscriptionOperation = ({ query: { definitions } }) =>
    definitions.some(
    ({ kind, operation }) =>
      kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription'
  );
```

and here's the client config:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
link: ApolloLink.split(
    hasSubscriptionOperation,
    wsLink,
    ApolloLink.from([
      cleanTypenameLink,
      authMiddleware,
      errorLink,
      stateLink,
      createUploadLink()
    ])
  ),
  cache
});
```

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this? (without using ws)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some searching i found that i can use SubscriptionClient from subscriptions-transport-ws

```
export const myClient = new SubscriptionClient(`ws://${hostname}${port ? 
`:${port}` : ''}/subscriptions`, {
 reconnect: true,
 connectionParams: () => ({
  authorization: localStorage.getItem('accelerator-token')
 })
});
myClient.onConnected(()=>{console.log("connected f client f onConnected")})
    myClient.onReconnected(()=>{console.log("connected f client f 
reconnected")})
myClient.onReconnecting(()=>{console.log("connected f client  f 
reconnecting")})
myClient.onDisconnected(()=>{console.log("connected f client  f 
onDisconnected")})
myClient.onError(()=>{console.log("connected f client  f onError")})
export const wsLink = new WebSocketLink(myClient);
```

These methods can be used to detect the network status

Comment: `onConnected` never fires for me. Does it for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with React I found this nice community package [react-apollo-network-status](https://github.com/molindo/react-apollo-network-status)